# MySQL: Find top-3-customers with within a time frame

Tags: php, mysql

I'm searching for a solution to this:

A customer can place a order with a price **x** at a time **y**. A customer can have unlimited number of orders.

I want to get the **z** top-customers with their ordering-amount within a time-frame (e.g.a month).

I'm stuck at the summing and the ordering / filtering to the top **z**.

Can you help me out? Thanks!

Comment: It'd be helpful if you post the table structure and the query you've done so far so we can see what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Given an orders table with customer_id, amount and time columns, you should be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT customer_id, sum(amount) AS total
FROM orders
GROUP BY customer_id
WHERE time BETWEEN start AND end
ORDER BY total DESCENDING
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is psuedo code, but I'd use something like:

```
select sum(order_total), client_id
from orders
where order_date between X and Y
group by client_id
order by sum(order_total)
limit 0, 10
```